# How can I perform load-distributed breakpoint testing with auto stop listener?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, breakpoints

If 4 machines are executing a breakpoint test simultaneously i.e. command is run at the same time on all 4 slaves from the master (Final report= merging all 4), and one of the machines satisfies the breakpoint criteria specified in the auto stop listener and ends the test.

Do I consider this as the breakpoint? How do I interpret the result of this breakpoint test? Should the test be stopped on rest of the machines if one machine reaches breakpoint? Is there a better method for load-distributed breakpoint testing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will get valid results because they will be rather considered as a separate test runs, especially given you use [Merge Results Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)

I would rather recommend switching to [Distributed Mode of JMeter execution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter), in this case you will get cumulative results automatically and test shutdown event will be propagated to all JMeter slaves in the cluster.

Also as per the [breakpoint testing definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Breakpoint_testing) the essential part is the system under test monitoring so make sure to have it in place as well because the real "breakpoint" might happen even before the Auto-Stop listener catches the failure criteria

Comment: Thanks for the input!
If I can figure out a way to properly merge the results to reflect a cumulative test, do I need to propagate the shutdown event to all the slaves like it would in distributed mode?
Also could you explain what procedure would I have to follow for "system under test monitoring" for a proper breakpoint test?